# Composing generator producer of values

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

How can I compose a producer generator that gets values externally with another generator? If `producer` yields a value within the generator then it works, but when I send a value with `next` I get `undefined`. Is there a way to do this?

```
function* producer() {
    while (true) {
        yield // want to send values here
    }
}

function* take(n, gen) {
    var i = 0
    for (var x of gen) {
        if (i <= n) {
            yield x // want the value sent to the producer
            i += 1
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
}

var prod = producer()
var res = take(5, prod)

// How can I send values to the producer
// and make the result yield those values?

res.next() // init
console.log(res.next(1)) // {value: undefined, done: false}
console.log(res.next(2)) // {value: undefined, done: false}
// ...

// I want to get
// {value: 1, done: false}
// {value: 2, done: false}
// ...
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want. Do you expect `prod.next` to be an identity function, and want to "call" that from `take`?

Comment: A producer should not consume values. Why do you try to send values to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a value which is sent to `next()`, you should use the result that is returned by yield. I am not quite sure what your end goal is, but here is your **modified example:**

```
let producer = function*() {
    var nextResult = undefined;
    while(true) {
        nextResult = yield nextResult;
        console.log("produce " + nextResult);
    }
}

let take = function*(number, items) {         
    var count = 0;
    var item = undefined;
    while (count <= number) {
        items.next(item);
        item = yield item;
        console.log("take " + item);
        count += 1;
    }
}

var res = take(2, producer())

res.next() // init
console.log('result ' + res.next(3).value)
console.log('result ' + res.next(2).value)
```

**This outputs:**

```
take 3
produce 3
result 3
take 2
produce 2
result 2
```

[ES6 fiddle link](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i91n9pu9/)